# how to set button for saving image on device

Tags: android, image, button, save

I am developing an app in which I have 3 buttons.  2 buttons are used to change the images and the 3rd should be used to save the current image in our device.I don't know how can I use the code for it. So plz help me with code. Here is my code.

Main java

```
Public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
int pos=0;
int amount=10;
int max=amount -1;
int min=0;
Button prev, next, save;
ImageView image;
Bitmap bitmap; 
final int [] imgs = new int [] {R.drawable.a1, R.drawable.a2, R.drawable.a3, //so on to a10};
@Override
Public void onCreat (Bundle savedInstance){
super.onCreat (savedInstanceState);
setContentView (R.layout.activity_main);
image=(ImageView) findViewById (R.id.ImageViewPic);
prev=(Button) findViewById (R.id.bprev);
next=(Button) findViewById (R.id.bnext);
save=(Button) findViewById (R.id.bsave);
image.setImageResource (R.drawable.a1);
prev.setOnClickListener (this);
next.setOnClickListener (this);
save.setOnClickListener (this);
}
@Override
public void onClick (View arg0) {
switch (arg0.getId ()){
case R.id.bprev:
if (pos > min) {
pos--;
image.setImageResource (imgs [pos]);
;
} else {
}
break;
case R.id.bnext:
if (pos < max) {
pos++;
image.setImageResource (imgs [pos]);
;
} else {
}
break;
case R.id.bsave:
// So here is the main thing. Which code I have to write here. Plz guide me.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this method to save Image of `ImageView`...

```
private void saveImage(ImageView imageView) {
    Drawable image = imageView.getDrawable();
    if(image != null && image instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) image;
        Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
        try {
            File file = new File("path where you want to save");
            FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            stream.flush();
            stream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
}
```